# Need to center ImageButton src, not stretch it to match the button size

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-imagebutton

I am learning to develop Android user interfaces. I want to create an ImageButton with a set of drawables to indicate different button states. I created two pictures for each button: 133 dp for normal state and a scaled copy (126 dp) to create the pushed button effect.

[image]

I painted the second picture to indicate that image selector mechanism works at least.

Here is the initial state of my application

[image]

When I push the button it changes only color but not the size as expected. Both images are fitted to the same size

[image]

Activity layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainUserActions"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:gravity="top">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/broom_stick_image_selection"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/vacuum_selection"
                android:scaleType="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

drawable selection xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/broom_stick_white_pressed_rose" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/broom_stick_white" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/broom_stick_white" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

How to tell the system just center the src images on the button layout, not to fit them to the same size?

Comment: Try setting the width and height of the ImageButtons to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to wrap the item in a `layer-list`, which allows for the definition of offsets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item
                android:drawable="@drawable/broom_stick_white_pressed_rose"
                android:top="2dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:left="2dp" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/broom_stick_white" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I see now that no need for additional images - the original image is enough!